# how to set font-size font-family

Tags: raphael

i have code like this but its not working

```
var t = r.text(100, 100, 'test');
t.attr({font-size: 16});
```

giving me error

```
missing : after property id
```

here is documentation for raphael.js
http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For attributes with a hyphen in the name, you need to use a string literal.

```
var t = r.text(100, 100, 'test');
t.attr({ "font-size": 16, "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" });
```

Comment: Can also shorten this to one statement with var t = r.text(100,100, 'test').attr({"font-size":16, "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" });}

Answer (score 0):

Check the below lines:

```
var text1 = paper.text(top, left, `Your Text`);
text1.attr({ "font-family": "arial", fill: "black", "font-size": 12 });
```